# Limit screen size for application

Tags: android

I develop the application on tablet and want to test it on smaller size screen. Can I configure it to limit width and height of the screen to emulate smaller screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on a physical device, no.

You can however create any number of AVDs to run in the emulator to mimic any screen size you wish. The "new AVD" wizard has a number of pre-defined skins. specifically, I see one listed as "WQVGA400" and "WQVGA432" that is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: may be I can use any special kind of `Layout` as root on every layout XML, set style for it and change dimension when need?

Comment: you should use the emulator. that's what it's for. if for some reason you can't use the emulator (e.g., you need hardware features that aren't implemented there), create mock objects to wrap the hardware you need so you can run in the emulator (e.g., MockCamera, etc).

Comment: you could *try* setting the width and height of the outer layout in your layout .xml to some values, in pixels. i'm not sure this will give the effect you want though.